# Conjugate Gradient guesses on a sequence of linear equation systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let us say that we have a sequence of linear problems

$${\bf L}_i{\bf x} = {\bf r}_i \,\,\, i \in \{0,1,\cdots, N\}$$

Where $\bf L_i \approx L_{i+1}, \bf r_i \approx r_{i+1}$, but $\|{\bf L}_N-{\bf L}_0\|>>0$ and $\|{\bf r}_N-{\bf r}_0\|>>0$

Furthermore assume we have solved $${\bf x}_0 = {{\bf L}_0} ^{-1}{\bf r}_0$$ to some satisfactory accuracy.

How can we utilize this knowledge in solving ${\bf x}_i,  \forall i >0$

Is there some way to estimate how many iterations of C-G we will need to run to solve these if we start the algorithm guessing that ${\bf x}_{k+1} = {\bf x}_{k}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recycling Krylov subspace approach is one option to handle these situations. See [SISC paper](http://www.siam.org/journals/sisc/28-5/60727.html) or [webpage](https://www.sandia.gov/~mlparks/software.html#Recycling)